# Counting how many times a function is called

Tags: c++

I want to count how many times a function is called, so that if it is called more than once, some error is notified to the developers (via logging, or asserting, and so on). I would like this code to be well defined and isolated so that it is easily portable across many function and member functions as well. Something as easy as:

```
void function( )
{
    if( is_called_more_than_once( ) )
    {
        // do something to handle the error
    } 
}

void AClass::method( )
{
    if( is_called_more_than_once( ) )
    {
        // do something to handle the error
    } 
}
```

Is it possible in C++, since it does not have reflection, to achieve something like that somehow?

Comment: Is this intended to be used for debugging purposes?

Comment: @VTT not strictly.

Comment: If this is intended to be used in production then you may want to write some kind of notification for monitoring software, for example `zabbix` or `collectd` counter. Notice that this approach delegates exact error handling to the person in charge of product support. If this is an error that is supposed to be handled in application then you may want to throw an exception and write an error handler code (that may still notify external monitoring software).

Comment: If Windows and Visual-Studio and (more restrictions), then maybe you can use penter and the /Gh hook? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 3):

For standalone functions, or static class methods, you can use a static local variable:

```
void function()
{
    static int num_called = 0;
    if( ++num_called > 1 )
    {
        // do something to handle the error
    }
    ...
}
```

For non-static class methods, use a class data member for each method, allowing individual instances of the class to do their own tracking:

```
class AClass
{
private:
    int num_method1_called;
    int num_method2_called;

public:
    AClass();

    void method1();
    void method2();

    ... 
};

AClass::AClass() :
    num_method1_called(0),
    num_method2_called(0)
{
}

void AClass::method1()
{
    if( ++num_method1_called > 1 )
    {
        // do something to handle the error
    }
    ...
}

void AClass::method2()
{
    if( ++num_method2_called > 1 )
    {
        // do something to handle the error
    }
    ...
}
```

If the error handling is always the same, consider extracting it to a reusable helper:

```
struct callTracker
{
    int counter;
    callTracker() : counter(0) {} 
    void called()
    {
        if( ++counter > 1 )
        {
            // do something to handle the error
        }
    }
};
```

```
void function( )
{
    static callTracker tracker;
    tracker.called();
    ...
}
```

```
class AClass
{
private:
    callTracker method1_tracker;
    callTracker method2_tracker;

public:
    void method1();
    void method2();

    ... 
};

void AClass::method1()
{
    method1_tracker.called();
    ... 
}

void AClass::method2()
{
    method2_tracker.called();
    ... 
}
```

Alternatively:

```
struct singleCallTracker
{
    int counter;
    singleCallTracker() : counter(0) {}
    void called()
    {
        if( ++counter > 1 )
        {
            // do something to handle the error
        }
    }
};

struct multiCallTracker
{
    std::map<std::string, singleCallTracker> trackers;
    void called(const std::string &name)
    {
        trackers[name].called();
    }
};
```

```
void function()
{
    static singleCallTracker tracker;
    tracker.called();
    ... 
}
```

```
class AClass
{
private:
    multiCallTracker method_tracker;

public:
    void method1();
    void method2();

    ... 
};

void AClass::method1()
{
    method_tracker.called(__FUNC__);
    ...
}

void AClass::method2()
{
    method_tracker.called(__FUNC__);
    ...
}
```

Comment: this doesnt satisfy the OP's orginal intent `well defined and as isolated as possible` perhaps a minimal class with a counter.

Comment: also, in the method case, this does not distinguish between different objects of the same class.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 Use data members...?

Comment: @RemyLebeau it requires to add a member for every method that needs to be tracked. Can it be done better maybe?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: You could update the tracker to use a `std::map` to keep track of multiple counters in a single container, then you would need only one tracker per class.  I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau (i) I'm confident it's `__func__`, not `__FUNC__`, and I otherwise think I prefer my version below that uses a set rather than a map. The question asks to distinguish only between first call and after-first calls, so there's no need to keep an explicit count. E.g. in your `multiCallTracker`, if there is anything in the map then that means definitely log. Doesn't matter what value the thing has. So my version is: don't store a thing. But whatever. Beyond splitting hairs, we're essentially much the same suggestion.

Comment: @Tommy: the OP's question clearly states: "*I want to **count how many times** a function is called*", so an integer counter may more appropriate than a boolean. Maybe he wants to include the current counter in his log message? We don't know. In any case, the *standard* may be `__func__`, but that wasn't added until C99 and C++11. Older compilers used `__FUNC__` or even `__FUNCTION__` instead. Check your particular compiler and tweak the code if needed.

Comment: The entire sentence is "I want to count how many times a function is called, **so that if it is called more than once**, some error is notified to the developers". The difference between zero and one is a very shallow form of counting. So I don't interpret that the same way that you do. Again, though: splitting hairs. I don't know who gave you negative votes, and I definitely don't agree with them for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection isn't necessary, because the caller is known as compile time. C++11 has a built-in `__func__` which evaluates as a plain-C string that is the unadorned name of the function. There is also `typeid(*this).name()` to get the mangled name of the class behind `*this`.

So define a class that maintains a set of strings and has a single method, `announce_call`. Put an instance of that class in every class you define, possibly by inheriting from someone that has a `protected` instance.

Call `announce_call` providing the function name and class name. If the function name is already within the set, log an error with it and the class name. Otherwise add it to the set.

Provide a global instance if desired, for functions that do not belong to classes.

So net per-class syntax cost is: adding an extra base class, adding an extra line at the start of every counted function.

Inheritance provides the main caveat: since `this` always points to an instance of the thing the function belongs to, if `B` inherits from `A` and `C` owns an instance `B` but calls a method from `A` twice, the log will show a double call to `A` rather than to `B`.

Comment: In the case of a method, this does not distinguish between different objects of the same class.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 that's true, and a fix would be awkward, once you consider the semantics. The knee-jerk would be to supply `this` as an extra indicator of caller, but then you've got to post a 'clear all' request during deconstruction which starts to add substantially to syntax overhead, and then support whatever you think is proper to do during moves (I'd assume carry the total over) with movable objects, plus copying considerations (in that it's probably contextual per-object whether a copy is a clean slate or just another representation of the same thing).

Comment: So, for the record, @nyarlathotep108's comment refers to a version of this answer that suggested using __FILE__ and __LINE__ as unique identifiers of each function, mapping to a table of call counts. It therefore failed to allow for multiple instances. The replaced answer that will appear momentarily differs so as to nullify his concern, because the original comment was valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is as close as you can get with a single macro:

```
#define if_called_more_than_once() \
    static int s_nTimesCalled = 0; if (++s_nTimesCalled > 1)

void function( )
{
    if_called_more_than_once()
    {
        // do something to handle the error
    } 
}
```